# How to use the same ClientWebSocket object in every call in .NET Core application

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket

I have a .NET Core API project, and in one of my requests I use a ClientWebSocket object to send and fetch data from my solar grid inverter, but the inverter only supports one client at the time, else the other one gets kicked. So I think I need to use the "same" client for all of my requests to be able to use multiple clients at the same time for my API controller.

My Controller has this endpoint:

```
readonly MyService myService = new MyService();

[HttpGet]
        [Route("GetEnergyParameters")]
        public List<EnergyParameter> GetEnergyParameters()
        {
            return myService.GetEnergyParametersAsync().Result;
        }
```

And "MyService" creates a ClientWebSocket at the top of the class like this:

```
 public class MyService
        {
    ClientWebSocket _wsClient = new ClientWebSocket();
    
    public List<EnergyParameter> GetEnergyParametersAsync() {
    ...
    }

}
```

But I get the exceptions:

```
The WebSocket is in an invalid state ('Aborted') for this operation
```

And

```
The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake
```

I belive this happens if I do multiple stuff at the same time, how can I fix this problem?

SendMessage Method:

```
internal async Task<string> SendMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);


            if (_wsClient.State != WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                await ConnectAsync();
            }

            await _wsClient.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);


            buffer = new byte[2048 * 2];

            // Perform the receive operation outside of the lock
            var result = await _wsClient.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await logger.CreateLog($"SendMessage failed, message = {message}, WebSocket state: {_wsClient.State}", ex.ToString(), 2);
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Best regards Max

Comment: A WebSocket and WebClient are not compatible.  Both client and server have to be the same.  A Websocket the connection stays open after each request/response while the Webclient the connection opens and closes after each request/response.

Comment: Did you try making `MyService` a singleton?

Comment: I have tried making it a singleton, but no difference, @jdweng, what do you mean with "not compatible"?

Comment: I have noticed that the problem occurs when I use my SendMessage twice without the first one completeing, I will update the main post with my sendmessage method, is there a way to "wait" for an asynchronos method to complete before the next goes through?

Comment: You are working once so type of connection is not an issue.  Many website allow only one connection.  You will get an error if you try a second connection. You may want to add a lock around posted code so you do not get two connection without the first closing.

Comment: I have tried to do that, but the methods are awaited and async, and you cannot await stuff inside a lock, is there som way I can "await" inside a lock? I dont think the ClientWebSocket has a Connect, read or write without async...

Comment: I tried something new now, it kinda works, but on the third message my ReciveAsync doesnt fetch any data, but if I use wireshark/fiddler I see that I get a response...